# Send Push Notification in C#

Tags: c#, push-notification, certificate, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I am trying to send push notification to iOS device with below coding in VS C# Web project.

Actually below coding without any error, but i didn't received any notification on my device finally, anyone have idea? thanks.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ApnsConfiguration(ApnsConfiguration.ApnsServerEnvironment.Sandbox, @"D:\Share\Certificates_Prod.p12", "");

        // Create a new broker
        var apnsBroker = new ApnsServiceBroker(config);

        // Wire up events
        apnsBroker.OnNotificationFailed += (notification, aggregateEx) => {

            aggregateEx.Handle(ex => {

                // See what kind of exception it was to further diagnose
                if (ex is ApnsNotificationException)
                {
                    var notificationException = (ApnsNotificationException)ex;

                    // Deal with the failed notification
                    var apnsNotification = notificationException.Notification;
                    var statusCode = notificationException.ErrorStatusCode;

                    Console.WriteLine($"Apple Notification Failed: ID={apnsNotification.Identifier}, Code={statusCode}");

                }
                else
                {
                    // Inner exception might hold more useful information like an ApnsConnectionException           
                    Console.WriteLine($"Apple Notification Failed for some unknown reason : {ex.InnerException}");
                }

                // Mark it as handled
                return true;
            });
        };

        apnsBroker.OnNotificationSucceeded += (notification) => {
            Console.WriteLine("Apple Notification Sent!");
        };

        // Start the broker
        apnsBroker.Start();

        apnsBroker.QueueNotification(new ApnsNotification
        {
            DeviceToken = "58f0f386003a4b7be..................................",
            Payload = JObject.Parse("{\"aps\":{\"badge\":7}}")
        });

        // Stop the broker, wait for it to finish   
        // This isn't done after every message, but after you're
        // done with the broker
        apnsBroker.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: What issue are you having? Is there no response to read to confirm your message was sent? Also what's   `int[] HexValue = new int[] {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0....` why so many `0x00`?

Comment: Now i didn't receive any notification, do you have any suggestion about the HexStringToByteArray funcation?

Comment: Yes, I posted it in my answer

Comment: Thanks ~~ i tried but still doesn't work.

Comment: You created a developer account and registered your app correct? Also is there a reason you are using legacy format?

Comment: I am new on the iOS notification, i dont know this is legacy format, but i think the part on developer account and app are fine, because i have success to send push notification from 3rd party program on Mac such as "APNS Push". do you have any suggestion to send from VS C# program? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the legacy API. There is 5 year complete C# walk though on it [here](https://arashnorouzi.wordpress.com/2011/03/31/sending-apple-push-notifications-in-asp-net-part-1/) if you wish to continue to use that.

Apple now supports APNs over http/2. Instead of writing your own code take a look at some existing libraries such as [PushSharp](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp) which will take care of the low level API and error handling for you.

```
// Configuration (NOTE: .pfx can also be used here)
var config = new ApnsConfiguration (ApnsConfiguration.ApnsServerEnvironment.Sandbox, 
    "push-cert.p12", "push-cert-pwd");

// Create a new broker
var apnsBroker = new ApnsServiceBroker (config);

// Wire up events
apnsBroker.OnNotificationFailed += (notification, aggregateEx) => {

    aggregateEx.Handle (ex => {

        // See what kind of exception it was to further diagnose
        if (ex is ApnsNotificationException) {
            var notificationException = (ApnsNotificationException)ex;

            // Deal with the failed notification
            var apnsNotification = notificationException.Notification;
            var statusCode = notificationException.ErrorStatusCode;

            Console.WriteLine ($"Apple Notification Failed: ID={apnsNotification.Identifier}, Code={statusCode}");

        } else {
            // Inner exception might hold more useful information like an ApnsConnectionException           
            Console.WriteLine ($"Notification Failed for some unknown reason : {ex.InnerException}");
        }

        // Mark it as handled
        return true;
    });
};

apnsBroker.OnNotificationSucceeded += (notification) => {
    Console.WriteLine ("Apple Notification Sent!");
};

// Start the broker
apnsBroker.Start ();

foreach (var deviceToken in MY_DEVICE_TOKENS) {
    // Queue a notification to send
    apnsBroker.QueueNotification (new ApnsNotification {
        DeviceToken = deviceToken,
        Payload = JObject.Parse ("{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + "Hi,, This Is a Sample Push Notification For IPhone.." + "\",\"badge\":1,\"sound\":\"default\"}}")
    });
}

// Stop the broker, wait for it to finish   
// This isn't done after every message, but after you're
// done with the broker
apnsBroker.Stop ();
```

Comment: Finally i follow your suggestion and update my coding reference to PushSharp instead, but still nothing happened, would you please have a look? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You Convert `HexStringToBytes` function is wrong. It has several `0x00` values in wrong places:

```
int[] HexValue = new int[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F };
```

It should be:

```
int[] HexValue = new int[] { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F };
```

I would also recommend something cleaner altogether. Try something like this:

```
public static byte[] HexStringToByteArray(string Hex)
{  
    if(1 == (Hex.length&1))  throw new Exception("Hex string cannot have an odd number of characters");
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length <<1 ) 
        .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x << 1, 2), 16)) 
        .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks~, I have tried your suggestion, but still doesn't work, still didn't received any notification

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed, it like APNS do not allow empty message, I updated payload JSON to:

```
JObject.Parse("{\"aps\": {\"alert\": \"joetheman\",\"sound\": \"default\"},\"message\": \"Some custom message for your app\",\"id\": 1234}")
```

It works for me.